# Combining multiple rows into one single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure like this one: 
[image: so_1.png]

I need to get the latest values of each column != NULL. My current approach is to use a `UNION`statement like this one:

```
SELECT TOP 1 testlong1_min, testlong1_max, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM Grenzwerte WHERE testlong1_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong1_max IS NOT NULL UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 NULL, NULL, testlong2_min, testlong2_max, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM Grenzwerte WHERE testlong2_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong2_max IS NOT NULL UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, testlong3_min, testlong3_max, NULL, NULL FROM Grenzwerte WHERE testlong3_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong3_max IS NOT NULL UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, testlong4_min, testlong4_max FROM Grenzwerte WHERE testlong4_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong4_max IS NOT NULL
```

This doesn't seem to work, my result is empty. I also thought about doing 1 query per field, but I guess that'll be too much of an overhead compared to the UNION-statement.

**Question:**

Is there a way to concenate the columns and return the latest values in one row?

**EDIT**

Using Parodo's suggestion I now get this result, now I need to combine the rows into one.

[image]

Comment: How do you define the latest?

Comment: you haven't shown the id column.

Comment: That's right, sorry. I had it sorted by id in the UNION-statement, but that's been a syntax-error (order is always on the last position, but I'll find a way to fix that. Maybe `latest` in my question wasn't the right word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bellow statement, each CTE will have all the respective non null couples only and will also get a row number where the latest id will have number 1. So then i only get the latest id based on rownumber for each CTE, so each will have only one row. That way CROSS JOINING will result in a single row having the needed results.

```
;WITH testLong1CTE AS
(
    SELECT testlong1_min, testlong1_max, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn
    FROM   Table
    WHERE  testlong1_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong1_max IS NOT NULL
),testLong2CTE AS
(
    SELECT testlong2_min, testlong2_max, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn
    FROM   Table
    WHERE  testlong2_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong2_max IS NOT NULL
),testLong3CTE AS
(
    SELECT testlong3_min, testlong3_max, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn
    FROM   Table
    WHERE  testlong3_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong3_max IS NOT NULL
),testLong4CTE AS
(
    SELECT testlong4_min, testlong4_max, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn
    FROM   Table
    WHERE  testlong4_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong4_max IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT testlong1_min, 
       testlong1_max,
       testlong2_min, 
       testlong2_max,
       testlong3_min, 
       testlong3_max,
       testlong4_min, 
       testlong4_max
FROM (SELECT testlong1_min, testlong1_max FROM testLong1CTE WHERE rn = 1) AS T1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT testlong2_min, testlong2_max FROM testLong2CTE WHERE rn = 1) AS T2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT testlong3_min, testlong3_max FROM testLong3CTE WHERE rn = 1) AS T3
CROSS JOIN (SELECT testlong4_min, testlong4_max FROM testLong4CTE WHERE rn = 1) AS T4
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `is not null` instead of `<> NULL` as below

```
SELECT TOP 1 testlong1_min, testlong1_max, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM Grenzwerte WHERE testlong1_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong1_max IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 testlong1_min, testlong1_max, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM Grenzwerte WHERE testlong1_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong1_max IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 NULL, NULL, testlong2_min, testlong2_max, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM Grenzwerte WHERE testlong2_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong2_max IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, testlong3_min, testlong3_max, NULL, NULL FROM Grenzwerte WHERE testlong3_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong3_max IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, testlong4_min, testlong4_max FROM Grenzwerte WHERE testlong4_min IS NOT NULL AND testlong4_max IS NOT NULL
```

Be careful with `UNION` because it eliminates duplicates. If you want to see duplicates use `UNION ALL` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you combine two queries using [UNION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator) operator, the resulting resultset is the unique rows from the concatenation of both queries and that's not what you intend. If you want a single row with the latest non-null values for each column you should first get the latest non-null values and join every column into the result.

```
; WITH
tab1 AS (
   SELECT TOP 1 testlong1_min, testlong1_max
   FROM Grenzwerte
   WHERE testlong1_min IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY [mySequenceColumn]
),
tab2 AS (
   SELECT TOP 1 testlong2_min, testlong2_max
   FROM Grenzwerte
   WHERE testlong2_min IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY [mySequenceColumn]
),
tab3 AS (
   SELECT TOP 1 testlong3_min, testlong3_max
   FROM Grenzwerte
   WHERE testlong3_min IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY [mySequenceColumn]
),
tab4 AS (
   SELECT TOP 1 testlong4_min, testlong4_max
   FROM Grenzwerte
   WHERE testlong4_min IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY [mySequenceColumn]
),
SELECT *
FROM tab1 CROSS JOIN tab2 CROSS JOIN tab3 CROSS JOIN tab4;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the edit I already made to Giannis answer, because it's easier to read. I already marked Giannis answer as solution, because he was first, but upvoted yours.

Comment: About Giannis answer, please note that, although it solves the problem, it is probably more resource intensive; since it only limits the number of rows on the main `SELECT`, it cannot take advantages of existing indexes the _sequenceColumn_ for the CTEs.